# Получить данные из формы, создать файл и вставить данные в файл - PHP

Tags: php

Есть форма на сайте. Я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы данные из формы передавались в файл обработчик формы со следующим кодом:

```
$post = $_POST["url"]; 
    $post = $_POST["id"]; 
$text = '/derictory/url.html';
file_put_contents("$text.html", "Произвольная информация + id", FILE_APPEND);
```

Что я пытаюсь сделать - получить из формы значения полей *url* и *id*. Создавать файл в *derictory*, и назвать его так, как было указано в поле *url*. Внутрь файла записать какую-нибудь информацию и *ID*, который тоже передается из формы.

В итоге получаю файл с названием `url.html`, а внутрь записывается только произвольная информация - *id* не прописывается.

Может быть, есть готовые решения данного вопроса?

Comment: Теперь ничего не происходит. Файл не создается. Права выставлены, все должно быть нормально. Но файл не создается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$post_url = $_POST["url"]; 
$post_id = $_POST["id"]; 
$text = "/directory/{$post_url}.html";
file_put_contents($text, "Произвольная информация + {$post_id}", FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Все работает! Осталась одна проблема - FILE_APPEND. Мне нужно, чтобы каждый раз, когда я обращаюсь к этому файлу, его содержимое перезаписывалось - а не "дописывалось". Как я понял, file_put_contents не может перезаписывать содержимое - только добавлять?

Comment: С этим сам разобрался. Если не писать FILE_APPEND - то файл перезаписывается. Огромное спасибо.